# Oil leaked after service

Tags: toyota

I had my car's oil and filter changed. Got home end later went our to do some errands. Car started making strange noises when I was making turns. Thought it was due to bumper maybe the tire was rubbing on it. The noise become more constant so I tried to get home. After oil change I drove  about 28 miles. When I was close to my driveway engine light came on oil temperature and all oil related lights on my dashboard. Shut the car off and restarted it so the car rolled in where I usually park. I looked on the ground and saw oil had spilled there this morning. When I checked oil the stick is almost bone dry. The car is 2 years old would it have effected the engine?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It's possible the engine was damaged either by running with insufficient oil, or by excessive temperature (which may have occurred *because* of the insufficient oil)...or it's possible that when the oil leak is repaired and the motor filled with oil again, it'll run just fine and won't have been damaged. Fix the leak, fill it with oil, and find out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that there was no leak before the oil and filter change, and that the leak was caused directly by the oil and filter change.

Most likely the oil filter has been dramatically overtightened, causing the rubber seal on it to split, allowing oil to leak out of it.

From where I am, it's impossible to tell if your engine is damaged. I would immediately stop driving the car, and change the oil filter. Ensure its not over-tightened (0.5 - 1 turns after its snug is enough), and refill the engine oil.

Comment: No there was no leak before but should not the engine light or oil something had come on doshbord? Until the engine was out of oil.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but normally the engine oil warning light will come on when the engine is running with pretty much no oil in it at all...

Comment: +1. To clarify further, the light is not a 'low oil' warning. It is a 'Critically low. **STOP NOW** warning'. And I think it is not even based on oil level but on oil pressure, but maybe more experience folk here on MVM&R can comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends when the oil started leaking.If the oil leaked only while the car was parked then there is no need to worry.However if you have driven the car while the oil was leaking chances are you would have damaged your engine.
As you have mentioned warning lights did not come on the dash there is a fair possibility the oil leaked while the car was parked.
If you have not driven it on a very busy road you can back trace a few miles to see if there is oil spillage on the road.
Also you can call the service centre to visit your place to have it inspected and top up the oil.

Answer (score 0):

The engine probably has some internal damage, but its probably going to be okay if it hasn't seized completely already. The only thing you can do is have it towed to a shop, have them do an oil change, check for leaks, and keep going. Have them check to see if you blew up the engine first though.